# Importing a python module into a dict (for use as globals in execfile())?

Tags: python, python-module

I'm using the Python `execfile()` function as a simple-but-flexible way of handling configuration files -- basically, the idea is:

```
# Evaluate the 'filename' file into the dictionary 'foo'.
foo = {}
execfile(filename, foo)

# Process all 'Bar' items in the dictionary.
for item in foo:
  if isinstance(item, Bar):
    # process item
```

This requires that my configuration file has access to the definition of the `Bar` class.  In this simple example, that's trivial; we can just define `foo = {'Bar' : Bar}` rather than an empty dict.  However, in the real example, I have an entire module I want to load.  One obvious syntax for that is:

```
foo = {}
eval('from BarModule import *', foo)
execfile(filename, foo)
```

However, I've already imported `BarModule` in my top-level file, so it seems like I should be able to just directly define `foo` as the set of things defined by `BarModule`, without having to go through this chain of `eval` and `import`.

Is there a simple idiomatic way to do that?

Comment: I don’t file evalfile exists; do you mean execfile?

Comment: Using eval is not the obvious idea IMO, because Python makes a distinction between expressions and statements.  eval can evaluate an expression (e.g. `eval('2 + 2')`), exec is for statements (e.g. `exec 'a = 2 + 2'`).  import is a statement.

Comment: @ÉricAraujo: I did mean execfile, yes; edits made.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `__dict__` defined by the module.

```
>>> import os
>>> str = 'getcwd()'
>>> eval(str,os.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the builtin [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) function to get the attributes of an object (such as a module) as a dict.

Answer (score 1):

The typical solution is to use getattr:

```
>>> s = 'getcwd'
>>> getattr(os, s)()
```